# Why is vim creating files with DOS line endings?

Tags: vim, windows, cygwin

I have

```
set fileformat=unix
```

in my `.vimrc`, and yet if I create a file in `vim` (running in Cygwin) it persists in creating DOS-format files, and I have to run them through `dos2unix` to clean them.  (I guess I don't really *have* to, since Git cleans them up for me, but it just bugs me to death that a Unix text editor, which I've specifically instructed to use Unix line endings, is polluting them with extra garbage.)

Why would this happen?  How can I fix it?  (And by "fix" I do *not* mean something that requires me to convert each file individually.  That's not a fix.  That's what's totally broken.)

Comment: I would wager this is a cygwin problem.  There is an option in cygwin to choose the line ending style but I hven't seen any evidence it actually works.  My university uses Eclipse with cygwin for the GNU compiler collection and I encountered a weird behavior with `getline` which turned out to be cygwin doing something weird.  Resulted in a `CR+LF` instead of the Unix `LF` or even a dos style `LF+CR`.  You should check and see what line ending style you have configured in cygwin but YMMV. See also http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.api.cr-lf

Comment: @Matt: DOS/Windows does use `CR+LF`, not `LF+CR`.

Comment: I was afraid I'd swap those if I didn't double check, been over a semester since I had that issue.  The line endings were different when running in cygwin and when running at the dos prompt and I remember being convinced it was backwards from what you'd expect from DOS but as you can see they're easy for me to switch up.

Comment: Are you sure that this .vimrc is even read? Try making a deliberate error and see if vim picks up on it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: yeah, I tested, and it is being read. I commented out my `set number` line, and it took effect, and uncommented it out and that took effect.  I also added "blah blah blah" at the bottom, and got "Press ENTER or type command to continue" when I opened anything, but oddly there was no error message before that (unless it was black letters on black background).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Setting only `fileformat` may not be enough, depending on a few factors. Try this:

```
set fileformat=unix
set fileformats=unix,dos
"set nobinary
```

To understand what these do, have a look at `:help fileformats`, etc.

I think I am able to reproduce your issues, using the `vim.exe` provided by `git` in windows. Using the above settings fixed the problem for me. In the example `set nobinary` is commented out because I don't think you need it, I left it there as a tip that might help in case you need to investigate further.