# Why am I getting "line 1: $' :\r': command not found"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cygwin, newlines

I use Cygwin on my laptop (DOS). I have a collection of scripts from my colleagues, and my own. I am not an IT person, not knowledgeable in Unix. I am following my colleagues' syntax and able to manage a few simple things.

The scripts worked well on my old laptop. I just changed laptop and installed Cygwin. When I run my scripts, they do not work. Here is one example of the error message I get:

```
line 1: $':\r': command not found
line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
line 5: `fi
```

Here are the top 5 lines of my script

```
:
iter=1
if [ -f iter.txt ]
   then rm ./iter.txt 
fi
```

Can someone please explain how I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have Windows-style line endings.

The no-op command `:` is instead read as `:<carriage return>`, displayed as `:\r` or more fully as `$':\r'`.

Run `dos2unix scriptname` and you should be fine.

---

If you don't have `dos2unix`, the following should work *almost* anywhere (and I tested on MobaXterm on Windows):

```
vi -b filename
```

Then in `vi`, type:

```
:%s/\r$//
:x
```

You're good to go.

---

In `vim`, which is what you are using on Cygwin for `vi`, there are multiple ways of doing this.  Another one involves the `fileformat` setting, which can take the values `dos` or `unix`.  Either explicitly change it after loading the file with

```
set fileformat=unix
```

or explicitly force the file format when writing out the file with

```
:w +fileformat=unix
```

For more on this, see the many questions and answers here covering this subject, including:

- [Remove ^M character from log files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88811/)
- [Why is vim creating files with DOS line endings?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44616/)
- [How to add a carriage return before every newline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153091/)

Comment: Just want to clarify, "iter=1" is my counter that will be used for the number of rounds of a math algorithm that my model will have to repeat later on  beyond line 5. I just posted the top 5 lines to go with the error message. All comments and instruction are greatly appreciated !!

Comment: I just tried the suggested command "$ tr -d  ..... "  but there is something wrong with my laptop. It does not go back to "$" but the ">     " appears on the screen instead. I have to use contrl C to get out. Then, I tested the script to see if the problem is fixed, but it is still there. Sorry, my knowledge in this field is very minimal ! I am trying to utilise my collection of scripts as they do help my work so much. Thank you everyone for being patient and helpful to me.

Comment: @TPham, see edit.  If this works be sure to use the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it.  (Accept whichever answer best solved your problem.)  https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I use VIM as my text editor. I did try ":%s/\r//g" previously and then your suggestion":%s/\r$//" but I still get the same error message "Pattern not found: \r". I have no idea what is happening!  Thanks for your instruction.

Comment: @TPham, did you use the `-b` flag when opening the file?  It won't work without that.  Read my answer carefully.

Comment: ah, my apologies ! I just repeat your instruction with -b, it works wonderfully. Thank you so much Wildcard !! You solved it !!
I will slowly go through and sort out other scripts now. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: Since the questioner uses `vim` rather than `vi`, this answer would do better to mention `vim`'s simple `fileformat=unix` setting, or even the `+ff` option to `write`.

Comment: @JdeBP, I think those are more complicated for this use case.  But by all means, please write an answer describing those and their relative benefits.  :)

Comment: Commands that are words are not really more complicated to a novice than a mysterious incantation that is almost wholly punctuation.  This does not need a separate answer.  It merely needs this answer to mention that `vim` can do this in two ways, one of which uses words.  Or, better yet, to point to _where this subordinate task has been answered over and over here_ in far more detail than _any_ answer on this page, including https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88811/ just for starters.

Comment: @JdeBP you've convinced me.  Would you mind editing it into this answer (with the link you mentioned)?  Put it under a line break at the bottom if you would be so kind.

Comment: Note that `vi -b`, `\r` are vim extensions anyway. not POSIX, not in nvi, elvis, Solaris vi...

Answer (score 10):

This is due to the script having been saved by an editor that uses DOS line-endings (such as Notepad++, for example).  You will have to remove these from your scripts.

To do this, either use `dos2unix` on the script file, or

```
$ tr -d '\r' <script >script.new && mv script.new script
```

(this will remove all carriage returns from *anywhere* in the script)

---

As for the code in the script:

```
:
iter=1
if [ -f iter.txt ]
   then rm ./iter.txt 
fi
```

This should possibly look something like

```
iter=1
if [ -f "./$iter.txt" ]; then
   rm "./$iter.txt"
fi
```

This removes the file `1.txt` from the current directory, if it exists.  The `:` command does nothing (almost) and may be removed.  The `iter` variable's value should be used as `$iter`, and be quoted. And then I'm possibly being more explicit than needs be by using `./` to say that the file needs to be found in the current directory.

If you're planning to turn this into a loop (here, deleting all files `1.txt`, `2.txt`, ..., `10.txt`):

```
iter=1
while [ "$iter" -le 10 ]; then
    if [ -f "./$iter.txt" ]; then
        rm "./$iter.txt"
    fi
    iter=$(( iter + 1 ))
done
```

Or, if we feel sneaky/lazy,

```
rm -f {1..10}.txt
```

in shells that understands brace expansion.

Comment: Notepad++ actually has the option to use Windows/Mac/Linux line breaks.  You just need to go to the Edit menu and then EOL Conversion->Unix (LF).  Or you could just double click in the bottom right corner where it says `Windows (CR LF)` and change it to `Unix (LF)`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your instruction. Would like to clarify: the "iter=1" is a counter that I use later on for my main objective, beyond line 5.

Comment: @TPham You're welcome. I was just bored and took your code and let my mind run impressionistic with it.

Comment: Or `rm -f [1-9].txt 10.txt`.  But that's not *totally* logically equivalent, as if there are no files 1-9 but there *is* a file literally called `[1-9].txt` then it will be deleted.  :D

Answer (score 5):

Your scripts have the wrong line-endings. Windows uses CR+LF (\r\n), Unix uses LF (\n), and Classic MacOS uses CR (\r). You'll need to change the line-endings on all affected files, either with a text editor or a standalone tool like `dos2unix`.

FTP and version control systems like SVN tend to be able to convert the line endings appropriately, so you might want to look into those options for transferring files in the future.

If these files *aren't* being transferred, but just used on a single machine, then you'll want to find the settings for line endings in your preferred text editor. Most that are advertised as "for programmers" will have such an option.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your helpful instruction. I just tried dos2unix but it seems I do not have it. Will search and try it again.

Answer (score 3):

As a supplemental answer let me add a couple notes/tips...

First, for regular text files you can easily determine whether they have Unix or DOS line ending using the `file` command. For example:

```
$ file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ dos2unix test.txt
dos2unix: converting file test.txt to Unix format...
$ file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text
```

Note my use of `dos2unix`. I highly recommend you install it. Depending on how you use Cygwin you may find you need to do this conversion often enough that the convenience is welcome. More importantly there is no chance of error like you get with the manual edits discussed here.

To install start the main Cygwin executable. That's the one with the name like setup-x86_64.exe or something along those lines. Make sure you see a screen like this:

[image]

Since you have already done the primary install you should be able to click *Next* all the way until you get the selection screen. Select Full in the dropdown and enter "dos2" in the search box and choose the tool as shown here:

[image]

Then click *Next* again and let the installation complete. That's it. Have fun. Cygwin, with the exception of this occasional inconvenience, is an awesome package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your instruction B Layer! This Stack Exchange group is so helpful. I really appreciate this support.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Notepad++** to edit my bash (.sh) scripts by connecting to the server by **WinSCP**
(To set up WinSCP editor to Notepad++ : https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editor_preferences )

This is very practical for opening files from servers to edit/save instead of "**Vim**" editor.
When you open the file in **Notepad++**, double-click on the 7th column at the status bar at the bottom and select "**Unix(LF)**".

[image]

Also, you have to change the 8th one by Encoding ->  Encode in UTF-8 in the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

If not dos2unix, there is also 'flip'

$ flip -u yourfilename.txt

will flip it to using unix line endings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the actual file's line encoding to have Cygwin's Bash happily work with Mac and Windows end-of-line encodings. There's an option you just need to flip on.

Just update your `~/.bash_profile` so it contains

```
export SHELLOPTS
set -o igncr
```

See https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/chess/softdevel/faq/5.html